# Problem reading list items from a custom SP list in a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, designer-workflow, json

I don't see any workflow 2013 action that would let me readily retrieve items from a custom list in a SP online team site. Therefore I have to rely on REST/_API calls as discussed in [this](http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=224) article. However I am not sure how do I get to the data from the JSON result I am receiving. Following is what it looks like when it is retrieved through the [Advanced REST Client tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US) in browser.

[image: JSON Response]

I need to loop through the whole **value** dictionary and get the **Title** properties for each item. For some reason I cannot get the value dictionary no matter whatever **item by name or path** I use in the **Get an item from a dictionary** action.

For test reasons as shown in the SP designer screenshot below, I am accessing the Title property at the 3rd index of the value block and saving the result into a test list. A record gets added but with empty value. 
At least, is it possible for me to verify if I am getting any data at all from the service call? How can I log the **JSONresults**, which is a dictionary variable? It also comes out empty when saved to the Test list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **d/results** works when put in for **item by name or path** . I don't know why the [Advance Rest Client Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US) is not showing **d** or **results** and instead shows **value**.